# error when springboot3 combines with mybatis-plus 3.5 and JDK 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-starter, mybatis-plus

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getTypeForFactoryBeanFromAttributes(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:86) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:838) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at com.web_chat_back.WebChatBackApplication.main(WebChatBackApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]

in my pom.xml:
springboot 3.2.0
mybatis-plus 3.5.3.2
jdk 17
mysql
jdbc
In addition,I added annotations "@Mapper" in xxMaperr and added annotations"@MapperScan("com.web_chat_back")"

Answer (score 6):

I suffered the same problem after upgrading to spring boot 3.2.
Upgrade dependencies to the latest version will do.

```xml
    <properties>
        <org.mybatis.version>3.5.14</org.mybatis.version>
        <org.mybatis.starter.version>3.0.3</org.mybatis.starter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mybatis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mybatis.starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Yep. In my case service is crashing after adding Feign dependencies. Solved by downgrading Spring Boot parent to `3.1.4`.

Comment: OK.Thank for your solution.I solved the problem.

Comment: spring boot 3.0.3 and mybatis starter 3.0.2 thrown the same issue, upgrading mybatis starter to 3.0.3 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use the mybatis starter dependency instead:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I solved this rollback the project version from <version>3.3.0-M1</version> to  <version>3.1.8</version>.